# Random bytes are added when sending files using C++ Sockets

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

When I send a file using C++ Socket, random bytes are added at the beginning. The problem occurs every few attemps. I tried to clear the buffers using different ways but nothing worked so far. I also noticed that in the received file i can see strings such as "File Size is".
I m using 2 Docker containers, each runs Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
This is the code i use to send the files:

```
int Socket::send_file(string path,int socket_){

    if (socket_ == -1 )
    {
        socket_ = clientSd ;
    }
    
    ifstream fichier ; 
    fichier.open(path,ios::in | ios::binary);  

    if (fichier.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File Opened " << endl ;
    }else
    {
        cout << "Failed to open file " << endl ;
        exit(0);
    }   

    int size =  get_file_size(fichier);

    fichier.close();
    
    char msg[MAX_BUFFER];                
    sprintf(msg, "%d\0", size);

    cout << "File Size is " << size << endl ;

    send(socket_, (char*)msg, sizeof(msg) , 0);  // 2 

    
    char buffer[MAX_BUFFER]; // 4222111
    const char *c = path.c_str();
    sprintf(buffer, "%d\0", size);
    FILE *fd = fopen(c, "rb");
    size_t rret, wret;
    int bytes_read;
    int fragment = MAX_BUFFER ;

    while (!feof(fd)) {
        if ((bytes_read = fread(&buffer, 1, MAX_BUFFER, fd)) > 0)
            send(socket_, buffer, bytes_read, 0);
        else
            break;
    }
    fclose(fd);

    cout << "End" << endl ;


    return 1 ;
}
```

This is the code i use to receive the files:

```
int Socket::receive_file(string path,int socket_){

    if (socket_ == -1 )
    {
        socket_ = clientSd ;
    }
    

        char* buffer ;
        buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_BUFFER) ;
        recv(socket_, (char*)buffer, MAX_BUFFER, 0); // 3
        int size =  atoi(buffer) ; 
        cout << "File Size is " << size << endl ;
        
        size_t datasize;
        char text[MAX_BUFFER]; // 1024
        const char *c = path.c_str();
        FILE* fd = fopen(c, "wb");
        int received = 0 ;

        while (received < size)
        {
            datasize = recv(socket_, text, sizeof(text), 0);          
            fwrite(&text, 1, datasize, fd); 
        }

        fclose(fd);
        cout << "End" << endl ;
        
    return 1 ;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. I see a mix of C and C++ functions, sounds not a very good idea. If you go for C++: did you have a look at boost::asio? It is supposed to wrap all the dirty stuff so you don't have to care about. Or other libraries (asio c++, ...)

Comment: The sender opens & closes a file without ever reading it, and then sends the full size of the file from a buffer you never initialized with anything. Then you reopen the same file with a different library, read it into _another_ buffer of the same size, and actually send it. Perhaps you have fragments of two different versions of your code mixed together?

Comment: @kebs Thanks I will check it.

Comment: `sprintf(buffer, "%d\0", size);` does not need `"\0"` in the format-string.

Comment: @Useless I didn't write the code. My task was just to dockerize the client and server but that introduced this problem. I will try to rewrite it if necessary

Comment: If you are concerned whether `size` will fit, you can validate the number of characters needed with `snprintf (NULL, 0, "%d", size);` and compare the return to `MAX_BUFFER` if the return is `>= MAX_BUFFER` then the buffer is too small to hold `size` as an integer converted to string including the nul-terminating character. (with `MAX_BUFFER` defined as `4222111` there is no chance that will happen). See [man 3 sprintf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) under the *RETURN VALUE* section.

Comment: `sizeof(msg)` is `MAX_BUFFER`. You probably want the length of the string instead.

Comment: If you're using TCP, it's an unstructured stream of data. There is no guarantee that the entire size string, or any part of it, occurs in your first `recv`. And there's even less of a chance that all the `MAX_BUFFER` data - most of it uninitialized - you sent first will be there.

Comment: On a side note, a habit of casting things to the type they already have may seem benign but is a likely source of very nasty bugs.

Comment: Well, this bug wasn't caused by dockerization unless you added a new uninitialized buffer and call to `send` as part of that. And if the code was broken _without_ docker ... you should be able to test that independently.